# I need some help for designing a table

Tags: sql, oracle, database-design, oracle10g

I would like to design a table for college mgmt system,for that I created a table(CollegeDetails) such a way that, it stores the college code(unique key),College name, course offered( EEE ,ECE,CSE…)…

#### CollegeDetails

```
CollegeCode   CollegeName   CourseOffered
--------------------------------------------
1000          xyz           EEE,ECE,CSE
1001          ABC           MECH,AERO,EEE
```

Here I am facing a problem. Each college contains many numbers of courses, for eg .xyz college offers 5 courses and abc college offers 8 courses… But I am not able to store in a single table, so I created two tables CollegeDetails and CourseOffered….

#### CollegeDetails

```
CollegeCode   CollegeName
--------------------------
1000          xyz
```

#### CourseOffered

```
CollegeCode   CourseOffer
-------------------------
1000          EEE 
1000          ECE
1001          EEE
```

But the CourseOffered table is getting duplicated(both the columns). Pls help to solve this …. I am using oracle 10g….

Comment: What do you mean it is "getting duplicated".  When you do what?

Comment: If by getting duplicated, you mean 2 or more records with the same CollegeCode and CourseOffer, you could prevent this through a checkconstraint to ensure a given combination could only be stored once, and therefore should be unique.

Comment: i thought that individual repetition of college code and  CourseOffered is duplicate. so now i can use this table design for my project.

Comment: should possibly be tagged "homework"?

Comment: I see - yes this design is OK.  It would be a duplicate if there were 2 rows for "1000 EEE", but the individual columns are allowed to contain the same values as on other rows provided the overall key for the row is not duplicated.  In CourseOffered, the key consists of the 2 columns together.

Answer (score 1):

A quick hack to keep duplicates out of the courseoffered table is to create a unique composite index on collegecode and courseoffer:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX <index_name> ON courseoffered(collegecode, courseoffer);
```

That does nothing about whatever process/logical problem you have that is inserting the same key multiple times, but putting the index on it will certainly point it out to you when you try to insert a duplicate, and hence where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

You could normalize it further by creating a Courses table, then linking to the Courses PK in your CourseOffered table. That way, you are storing the course name, e.g. 'EEE', in a single place.